# System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'between'.'

Tags: c#

```
SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("Select * from salestable where empid='"
+ txtsid.Text
+ "'between'"
+ datepick1.Value.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")
+ "'And'"
+ datepick2.Value.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")
+ "'", con);


DataTable dt = new DataTable();
sda.Fill(dt);
```

Comment: You need to learn to use [parameterized SQL queries](http://bobby-tables.com/csharp). Not only will they make this kind of mistake less likely, they'll help prevent SQL Injection attacks.

Comment: There is no space around `between` and `And`

Comment: @mason i post a new answer,  its better?

Answer (score 1):

try use parameters on sqlDataAdapter:

```
        string SQLsentence = @"
SELECT * 
FROM salestable 
WHERE empid=@Employe
    AND [datesale(your column with date)] between @fDate And @lDate
";
        SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter ( SQLsentence , con );

        sda.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add ( new SqlParameter ( "@Employe" , txtsid.Text ) );
        sda.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add ( new SqlParameter ( "@fDate" , new DateTime ( 2018 , 06 , 1 ) ) );
        sda.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add ( new SqlParameter ( "@lDate" , new DateTime ( 2018 , 06 , 14 ) ) );
```

whe you use parameters you prevent the SQL injection.

Answer (score 0):

You don't seem to be testing a field for the between. It looks like the sql rendored will be something like:

```
Select * from salestable where empid='x'between'mm/dd/yy'and'mm/dd/yyyy'
```

you aren't testing anything as being between those two date values. Plus your spacing makes the sql hard to read

Comment: I am not getting what you guys are trying to tell me.

Comment: Fixed it. i was missing "AND" just before "BETWEEN" and table column name "salesdate"

"Select * from salestable where empid='"+txtsid.Text+"'and salesdate Between'"+date1+"'And'" +date2+ "'"

Thank you all for trying to help me. Jegan

Answer (score -1):

Fixed it.  i was missing "AND" just before "BETWEEN" and table column name "salesdate"

"Select * from salestable where empid='"+txtsid.Text+"'**and salesdate Between**'"+date1+"'And'" +date2+ "'"

Thank you all for trying to help me.
Jegan

Comment: Your code is still vulnerable to SQL Injection attack and you need to fix it

Comment: how do i do that?

Comment: Did you look at my comment on your question that received 8 upvotes?